# Reading Server Side Events in Python using sseclient

Tags: php, python, server-sent-events

I'm new to Server Side Events and started some tests with PHP on the server side and Python on the client side using the [sseclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sseclient/0.0.8) library.

Using a very basic PHP script, based on the [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) I can see the data being received in Python:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}


$time = date('r');
// echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
// flush();
sendMsg(time(),"The server time is: {$time}\n\n");


?>
```

and in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sseclient import SSEClient

messages = SSEClient('http://pathto/myscript.php')
for msg in messages:
    print msg
```

As a second step I've tried sending data read from an array stored in the `$_SESSION` variable. This seems to work when I connect to the SSE stream from javascript in the browser, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

Here's my basic PHP script:

```
<?php

session_start();

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}

// check for session data
if (isset($_SESSION["data"])){

    #as long there are elements in the data array, stream one at a time, clearing the array (FIFO)
    while(count($_SESSION["data"]) > 0){

        $serverTime = time();
        $data = array_shift($_SESSION["data"]);
        sendMsg($serverTime,$data);

    }
}

?>
```

and the Python script is the same.

Why isn't the sseclient Python script picking up the events from the above PHP script (while a basic JS one does) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP session variable is sent as a cookie; if you view your JavaScript version with Firebug (or equivalent) you should see the cookie being sent to the SSE server script.

So you'll need to set up a session for the Python script, and have it send that in a cookie too.

You could confirm this guess by adding some error handling to your PHP script:

```
...
if (isset($_SESSION["data"])){
   //current code here
}else{
   sendMsg(time(), "Error: no session");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darren (+1). I see "Error: no session" indeed. How do I set up a session for the Python script ? (or where can I find docs for this) ?

Comment: In CasperJS, I'd do this by making a request to an html page first, with a cookie file set up (so casper - actually the underlying phantomjs/slimerjs engine - records the cookie then sends it back on each request). If the Python sseclient library does not have any built-in support, you'll need to use another Python http client library to do the request, extract cookies, then add a custom header to your sse request.  (Probably just as quick to patch in cookie support to sseclient, though!)